# UIPageViewController caching issue

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController to scroll between five pages very similar pages. I am using the app delegate to refresh the view anytime applicationWillEnterForeground is called. (It does so by calling viewDidLoad in my PageViewController.)

I am storing the current index for my PageViewController in a NSUserDefault variable. But here's the problem.  Apparently, UIPageViewController uses a cache which means it doesn't always call its methods, which means the index number I store is rarely correct.

The result is, when I close the app and reopen it, it will refresh the view and show whatever page is associated with the last index I stored -  which is usually not the current index.

My question then is, what is the best way to refresh the current view when my app reenters the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use the delegate method: 
- pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:

Getting the current index is as simple as

```
let index = (pendingViewControllers[0] as! ViewController).index
```